# ShellExecute a cmd prompt with a specific working directory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmd

I want to launch an elevated command prompt in Windows to a specific working directory. So for example, I have tried this:

```
ShellExecute(
    hWnd,
    L"runas",
    L"cmd.exe",
    NULL,
    m_szSelectedFile,
    SW_SHOW
);
```

Where `m_szSelectedFile = L"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop"`

`ShellExecute` is documented as

```
HINSTANCE ShellExecute(
  _In_opt_ HWND    hwnd,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpOperation,
  _In_     LPCTSTR lpFile,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpParameters,
  _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpDirectory,
  _In_     INT     nShowCmd
);
```

Unfortunately, it always launches to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is mainly to do this in C++. Just create a shortcut.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That doesn't provide the functionality I want. I can do this in .NET no problem, I think `cmd` supports this irrelevant of the language

Comment: "That doesn't provide functionality" is nonsense. But anyway, for parameters (currently NULL), you can add e.g. `"/k cd \" + path + "\""`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft added this as a security feature starting in Windows 8.  Whenever cmd.exe detects it's running elevated, it ignores its launch parameters and always starts in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.  You cannot override this behavior.

You can, however, change directory as the first command in the prompt.  To do this, set `lpFile` to `"cmd.exe"` as normal.  Then set `lpParameters` to `"/k cd /d d:\your\path"`.  CMD will change directories immediately on launch, and then stay open for further commands.

Answer (score -1):

i test solutions, but any not working, but finnaly i search one solution:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    TCHAR szPath[_MAX_PATH];
    VERIFY(::GetModuleFileName(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, szPath, _MAX_PATH));
    CString csPath(szPath);
    CString csParameter;
    int nIndex = csPath.ReverseFind(_T('\\'));
    if (nIndex > 0)
    {
        csPath = csPath.Left(nIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        csPath.Empty();
    }

    if (IsWow64())
    {
        m_StatusText += "The process is running under Windows 64\r\n";
        UpdateData(false);
        csPath += "\\driverKey64";
        csParameter += "/c install.cmd";
        if (ShellExec(csParameter, csPath, true))
        {
            m_StatusText += "Drivers Installed\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            m_StatusText += "Drivers were not Installed\r\n";
        }
        UpdateData(false);
    }

int CDriverKeyDlg::ShellExec(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,LPCTSTR lpDirectory, bool bWait)
{
    int iReturn = -1;
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExInfo = { 0 };
    shExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExInfo);
    shExInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shExInfo.hwnd = 0;
    shExInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");          // Operation to perform
    shExInfo.lpFile = _T("cmd.exe");        // Application to start    
    shExInfo.lpParameters = lpApplicationName;    // Additional parameters
    shExInfo.lpDirectory = lpDirectory;
    shExInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    shExInfo.hInstApp = 0;

    if (ShellExecuteEx(&shExInfo))
    {
        if (bWait)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(shExInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        }
        iReturn = 1;
    }
    CloseHandle(shExInfo.hProcess);
    return iReturn;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the file "install.cmd"  are batch file and stored in folder: path executable module + "driverKey64", drivers for this sample are stored in this folder and batch execute from this folder without error..
Test in windows 64 bits 7,8,10,xp is similar for 32 bits ... coded MFC C++

regards