# ShellExecuteExW function with lpVerb = L"runas" and lpFile = L"cmd" succeeds but fails

Tags: winapi, elevated-privileges, runas, shellexecuteex

I have a unit test for a class that is intended to run shell commands with elevated privileges. A simple test case is to copy a test file into `C:\Program Files`. The class makes a call to the C function `ShellExecuteExW` function with `lpVerb = L"runas"` and `lpFile = L"cmd"` set in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW` argument. The call  succeeds without any errors and the details in the UAC elevation prompt are all correct, but when I look for the test file in program files, it is not there.

I am using an Eiffel compiler that generates cryptic looking MSVC compiled C code, but this is what the code would look like if manually written in C. Note that in the actual code, `%TEMP%` is already expanded.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main() {
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW shExecInfo = { 0 };

    // Set the structure size
    shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW);

    // Specify the operation to perform
    shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas"; // "runas" elevates the privileges

    // Specify the file or folder to be copied
    shExecInfo.lpFile = L"cmd";

    // Specify the parameters (in this case, the copy command)
    shExecInfo.lpParameters = L"/C /U copy data\\txt\\file.txt \"C:\\Program Files\" 2> %TEMP%\\copy-errors.txt";

    // Specify the working directory
    shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;

    // Set the show property
    shExecInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;

    // Execute the operation
    if (ShellExecuteExW(&shExecInfo) == FALSE) {
        // Handle error
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError == ERROR_CANCELLED) {
            // The user refused the UAC prompt
            printf("User refused the UAC prompt.\n");
        } else {
            // Other error
            printf("Error: %lu\n", dwError);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I run the unit test and I get the expected elevation prompt, and all the details of the command are correct.

## UAC prompt

[image]

After clicking OK, the command returns without error, but the test file is not being copied into `C:\Program Files` as expected. If I manually open a shell with admin privileges and copy/paste the exact same command, it succeeds and the file is actually copied. So I am mystified why this is not working in the C call.

The Eiffel Unit test which calls `ShellExecuteExW`

```eiffel
test_admin_level_execution
   -- OS_COMMAND_TEST_SET.test_admin_level_execution
   note
      testing: "[
         covers/{EL_WINDOWS_ADMIN_SHELL_COMMAND}.execute,
         covers/{EL_WINDOWS_ADMIN_SHELL_COMMAND}.set_command_and_parameters
      ]"
      status: "[
         Commented out in `make_named'. Failing on Windows
      ]"
   local
      command: EL_OS_COMMAND_I; destination_path: FILE_PATH
   do
      if Executable.Is_work_bench then
         create {EL_COPY_FILE_COMMAND_IMP} command.make ("data/txt/file.txt", Directory.applications)
         command.administrator.enable
         command.execute
         assert ("successful", not command.has_error)
         destination_path := Directory.applications + "file.txt"
         if destination_path.exists then
            create {EL_DELETE_FILE_COMMAND_IMP} command.make (destination_path)
            command.administrator.enable
            command.execute
            assert ("File deleted", not destination_path.exists)
         else
            failed ("File exists")
         end
      end
   end
```

The test fails at the point it checks to see if the file is copied. I have also manually checked in File Explorer.

**Alternative Method**

In an attempt to find a workaround I am also trying an alternate function: (but the outcome is the same)

```c
    HINSTANCE ShellExecute (
        _In_opt_ HWND    hwnd,
        _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpOperation,
        _In_     LPCTSTR lpFile,
        _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpParameters,
        _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpDirectory,
        _In_     INT     nShowCmd
    );
```

**Environment**

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64

OS: Windows 7

Comment: What's `SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW`?

Comment: Examine the contents of `copy-errors.txt` and the problem will be obvious. Hint: order of command line parameters matters.

Comment: copy-errors.txt contains no errors

The command OS API I am using is already tried and tested for non-elevated privilege, using a different C call.

Comment: SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW struct assumes wide character strings, i.e. UTF-16 encoded

Comment: I know of [`SHELLEXECUTEINFOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow) and [`SHELLEXECUTEINFOA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa) (and there's probably also `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`). But `SHELLEXECUTEINFOAW` doesn't exist anywhere in the SDK header files. Is that a typo?

Comment: If it was a typo I would not be able to compile the code: Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow

Comment: It *is* a typo, as is the command line you provided (it differs from what is shown in the screenshot). You probably need to double quote the entire command line passed to the /c parameter.

Comment: The UAC dialog crops the command line to some maximum length which is why th screenshot is different. I have tested the command in an admin shell, and it works in the shell. Any example I have seen does not quote the command line.

Comment: I don't know how you compiled the code, but [it doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/Gcob4KooG) for me.

Comment: The C code I gave is for illustrative purposes only and I did not try compiling it. But my Eiffel compiler generates C code which does compile and run. However this generated code is not human readable, which is why I made the sample code.

Comment: Is virtualstore interfering? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore

Comment: I noticed that, while the destination path is absolute, the source path of the copy is not. Are you sure about the "CWD"? Did you try to make the source path absolute as well? (For saftety reasons this might be a good idea anyway).

Comment: I did try explicitly setting the CWD using the lpDirectory field in the struct argument, but it didn't make any difference. I must try it as well with the alternative function I found

Comment: This file redirection hypothesis is interesting. I will investigate further. Thanks for tip.

Comment: I did find a directory `C:\Users\finnian\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files` but it did not contain `file.txt', so perhaps it is not a redirection problem.

Comment: I tried making the source path absolute but it had no effect on the problem. I also tried setting lpDirectory for the alternative method I mentioned, and that had no effect.

Comment: The commands are different. In the code you have `/C /U` while the screenshot shows `/U /C`. The order is important.

Comment: Luke pointed out that `/C` comes after `/U'. The Eiffel version has the correct order. The order in the C illustration code was a typo. My bad.

Comment: Thank a mil Luke for your very helpful suggestions, and I have noted about `std_err` on the `copy` command. And thanks to everyone who contributed their thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that apparently when cmd is launched elevated it does not honor the current directory and instead uses the system32 folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034535/179634

So you need to either specify the full path in the parameter to the `copy` command, or change the current directory in your command line using the `cd` command.

Comment: As an aside, in this case the `copy` command writes failure output to `stdout` instead of `stderr` so you might want to redirect `stdout` to a file as well.

Comment: See also: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071211-00/?p=24223

Answer (score 1):

As Luke pointed out, when `cmd` is launched elevated it does not honor the current directory and instead uses the system32 folder. The solution Luke offered was very helpful, but did not solve the problem completely as I will explain. I tried using this sequence of command parts:

**Debugger View**

[image: Eiffel Debugger View]

When I manually inspected the output folder, I could see `file.txt`, but the unit test was still failing. Why was that? Turns out the `ShellExecute` runs asynchronously, so I need some way to wait until the process finishes. The solution I came up with is shown in the code fragment below. (Note anything prefixed with `c_' is a C call from Eiffel)

```eiffel
class
   EL_WINDOWS_SHELL_COMMAND

inherit
   EL_ALLOCATED_C_OBJECT
      rename
         make_default as make
      redefine
         make
      end

feature -- Basic operations

   execute
      local
         n: INTEGER
      do
         c_set_n_show (self_ptr, show_type)
         if c_shell_execute (self_ptr) then
         -- make asynchronous process appear to be synchronous
            n := c_wait_for_single_object (process_handle)
            if c_close_handle (process_handle) then
               do_nothing
            end
            is_successful := n >= 0
         end
      end

feature {NONE} -- Implementation

   process_handle: NATURAL
      do
         Result := c_process (self_ptr)
      end

end
```

Class `EL_WINDOWS_SHELL_COMMAND` is a wrapper for the C Struct
`SHELLEXECUTEINFOW`.

**Note to self**

I need to ask Stackoverflow to improve the syntax highlighting for Eiffel